# Height of diff mode buttons is larger than needed in revisions list

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list

Areas marked with red rectangles are excessive in the post [revisions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/307175/revisions):

> [image: diff mode]

Seems there is some css issue.